# What does this raw-score value in the JSON output correspond to in the watson personality-insights demo?

Tags: json, personality-insights

In the JSON output posted below, do the final two lines shown in bold ("raw_score": -0.09740164166430795 & "raw_sampling_error": 0.0014781075199999999) provide the raw score value for "id": "Openness"?

{
  "id": "*UNKNOWN*"
  "source": "*UNKNOWN*",
  "word_count": 7066,
  "processed_lang": "en",
  "tree": { 
    "id": "r",
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "personality",
        "name": "Big 5",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "Conscientiousness_parent",
            "name": "Conscientiousness",
            "category": "personality",
            "percentage": 0.14979622860283198,
            "children": [
              {
                **"id": "Openness",**  
                "name": "Openness",
                "category": "personality",
                "percentage": 0.5302158140365638,
                "sampling_error": 0.0503447424,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": "Adventurousness",
                    "name": "Adventurousness",
                    "category": "personality",
                    "percentage": 0.47053613413656625,
                    "sampling_error": 0.044388585919999994,
                    "raw_score": -0.07711151995471272,
                    "raw_sampling_error": 0.0043414752
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "Artistic interests",
                    "name": "Artistic interests",
                    "category": "personality",
                    "percentage": 0.018466744070567406,
                    "sampling_error": 0.09150467896,
                    "raw_score": 0.0007939428247947908,
                    "raw_sampling_error": 0.00224603032
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "Emotionality",
                    "name": "Emotionality",
                    "category": "personality",
                    "percentage": 0.2693720266042174,
                    "sampling_error": 0.04087642816,
                    "raw_score": 0.05248938579111236,
                    "raw_sampling_error": 0.00475693816
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "Imagination",
                    "name": "Imagination",
                    "category": "personality",
                    "percentage": 0.5047725423239968,
                    "sampling_error": 0.0550909316,
                    "raw_score": -0.05644777809227285,
                    "raw_sampling_error": 0.00316281344
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "Intellect",
                    "name": "Intellect",
                    "category": "personality",
                    "percentage": 0.7676852305353833,
                    "sampling_error": 0.04775897016,
                    "raw_score": -0.05477073308802718,
                    "raw_sampling_error": 0.00537532176
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "Liberalism",
                    "name": "Authority-challenging",
                    "category": "personality",
                    "percentage": 0.4605497169149773,
                    "sampling_error": 0.07363731496,
                    "raw_score": -0.08313189923577696,
                    "raw_sampling_error": 0.00608654168
                  }
                ],
                **"raw_score": -0.09740164166430795,

                "raw_sampling_error": 0.0014781075199999999**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those values refer to the trait in the same element, which is "Openness". The formatting sometimes puts the children array in the middle so makes it a bit harder to read.